# How to get result from parent child table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Work on **SQL-Server**. My table structure is below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgentInfo](
    [AgentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AgentInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AgentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[AgentInfo] ([AgentID], [ParentID]) VALUES (1, -1)
INSERT [dbo].[AgentInfo] ([AgentID], [ParentID]) VALUES (2, -1)
INSERT [dbo].[AgentInfo] ([AgentID], [ParentID]) VALUES (3, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[AgentInfo] ([AgentID], [ParentID]) VALUES (4, 2)
```

**Required output**

Use my below syntax get required output but not satisfied. Is there any better way to get the required output

[image]

```
--get parent child list
---step--1 
SELECT * 
INTO #temp1 
FROM  ( SELECT a.AgentID ,
            a.ParentID,
            a.AgentID AS BaseAgent
        FROM dbo.AgentInfo a WHERE ParentID=-1
        UNION ALL         
        SELECT   a.ParentID  ,
            0 as AgentID,
            a.AgentID AS BaseAgent 
        FROM dbo.AgentInfo a WHERE ParentID!=-1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT   a.AgentID  ,
            a.ParentID,
            a.AgentID AS BaseAgent 
        FROM dbo.AgentInfo a 
        WHERE ParentID!=-1 
     ) AS d

SELECT * FROM #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp1
```

Help me to improve my syntax. If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: what is `baseagent` column?

Comment: I think it's for multi root tree selecting... I would suggest using nested sets through. They are easier to select and faster to select. If your tree does change often it's not as good through.

Comment: I don't understand that if agent 3 and 4 has a parent as 1 and 2, then why agent 1 and 2 has the parent as 3 and 4 too. A child can't be the parent of its parent. Something is very confusing here.

Comment: András Ottó  thanks for reply ,please check my currection

Comment: This correction makes even less sense... The BaseAgent column is now totally off. Your BaseAgents are 1 and 2, right?

Comment: You should explain what does BaseAgent, AgentID and ParentID means, because I can't understand you result table, and a recursion is not possible to achive this kind of data, because it would be an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive `SELECT`, see the examples in [the documentation for WITH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.90).aspx), starting with example D.

The general idea within the recursive `WITH` is: You have a first select that is the starting point, and then a UNION ALL and a second `SELECT` which describes the step from on level to the next, where the previous level can either be the result of the first select or the result of the previous run of the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, to get a tree of the elements:

```
WITH CTE_AgentInfo(AgentID, ParentID, BaseAgent)
AS(
  SELECT 
    AgentID,
    ParentID,
    AgentID AS BaseAgent
   FROM AgentInfo
   WHERE ParentID = -1
  UNION ALL
     SELECT 
    a.AgentID,
    a.ParentID,
    a.AgentID AS BaseAgent
   FROM AgentInfo a
   INNER JOIN CTE_AgentInfo c ON
    c.AgentID = a.ParentID
  )
SELECT * FROM CTE_AgentInfo
```

And here is an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08b9c/24) demo to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
WITH Merged (AgentId, ParentId) AS (
     SELECT AgentId, ParentId FROM AgentInfo WHERE ParentId = -1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT AgentInfo.AgentId, AgentInfo.ParentId FROM AgentInfo INNER JOIN Merged ON AgentInfo.AgentId = Merged.ParentId
)
SELECT * FROM Merged
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) to do this.

The sql statement will then look like this:

```
WITH [Parents]([AgentID], [ParentID], [BaseAgent])
AS
(
    SELECT 
      [AgentID],
      [ParentID],
      [AgentID] AS [BaseAgent]
    FROM [AgentInfo]
    WHERE [ParentID] = -1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      [ai].[AgentID],
      [ai].[ParentID],
      [p].[BaseAgent]
    FROM [AgentInfo] [ai]
    INNER JOIN [Parents] [p] 
      ON [ai].[ParentID] = [p].[AgentID]
)

SELECT *
FROM [Parents]
ORDER BY 
  [BaseAgent] ASC,
  [AgentID] ASC
```

But, the results are different from your desired output, since every Agent is only listed once.
The output is:

```
AGENTID     PARENTID    BASEAGENT
1           -1          1
3            1          1
2           -1          2
4            2          2
```

The Fiddle is over [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08b9c/27).

And here is a nice post on working with hierarchies: [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)